# SQL Server: DELETE duplicates WHERE DATE IS < DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table structure:

```
UNIQUE ID | TYPE | QUARTER | DATE
1         |    1 |     JAN | 2/2/2222
2         |    1 |     JAN | 4/2/2222
```

How do I delete the duplicate record that has an older date?

Comment: What sql-server version?

Comment: @alex I think it's 2008. It's the one built-in with VS2010. I'm not sure though.

Comment: What if Type is 2, Quarter Jan and Date 5/2/2222, do you need to delete. Or in other words do you need to group  by just Quarter or by Type too?

Comment: Are you positive you are using SQL Server 2008? If you execute `Select @@Version` against the database server what version does it claim to be?

Comment: I'll be interested to see what the results of @@version is.  The windows functions were introduced in 2005 so unless they've found a 2000 MSDE instance, I have no idea why the row_number call would fail

Answer (score 3):

In MS SQL 2008:

```
with cte
as
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by Quarter order by Date) RowNumber
    from MyTable
)
delete cte
where RowNumber > 1
```

In any sql

```
delete
from MyTable
    where Date not in
    (
        select Quarter, Min(DATE)
        from MyTable
        group by Quarter
    )
```

Assuming no duplicate Date fields.

Comment: @alex it says: `The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported.`

Comment: @Pod Mays - this is why I asked about the version. Can you try another query? I assuming that you don't have duplicate Date.

Comment: @Pod Mays: Try googling the very message. From what I've gathered so far, it seems like the error is generated by the VS's query builder, which for some reason does not support the OVER construct.

Comment: I will point out that this will only work if you are using a date or datetime dataype. If you have a poor design and are storing dates are varchar or nvarchar the ordering will not work correctly (strings sort differently than dates) and you could delete the wrong one.

Comment: @Pod Mays and @Andriy M, why would anyone be using a query builder to write SQL? Typically they do not let you use the more advanced query techiniques and they are often create poor SQL anyway.

Comment: @HLGEM: Can't say, never used them myself. I was only conjecturing as to what could be the cause of the problem and the reason for it, based on what I could find out with Google. I thought, if the IP did use the query builder, they should better read the material by themselves.